# Cannot Boot from 17.04 USB

Tags: boot, usb

I have created a usb flash drive in Ubuntu 16.04 using Startup disk creator, unetbootin, dd and the restore disk image in Disks. I have used the ubuntu 17.04 image and the Kubuntu 17.04 image. The MD5 hashes are correct. And my PC just sits there and nothing happens. With different usb sticks.

If I use the Lubuntu 17.04 image then everything works normally. Same usb stick.

I have tried on a second PC - also does not even reach the POST.

How is this a duplicate question? I can make a bootable USB but it will not boot if I use a 64 bit image even though the PC currently uses 64bit Ubuntu?

All I want to do is install Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Please tell us about your computer, at least: brand name, model, amount of RAM, graphics chip/card, wifi chip card. It makes it easier for us to help you. (Since the ultra lightweight Lubuntu works, I can guess that the other flavours of Ubuntu are too demanding for some of your hardware.)

Comment: It is a dual core pentium. 4Gb Ram. Good enough for 16.04 LTS so should be good enough for 17.04?

Comment: Do not have the bandwidth to do minimal - I already have the complete 17.04 image. Several of them. Maybe the only difference is 64bitUbuntu/Kubuntu vs 32 bit Lubuntu. Currently using 16.04 Ubuntu 64bit.

Comment: Is Lubuntu 32-bit (i386)? Check with `uname -a` What about the graphics card? I know that the Lubuntu developers have made an effort to install suitable software for some old Intel graphics cards to make it work well with old computers. Maybe that makes a difference. (I use Lubuntu, and I would definitely use it in a computer with dual core pentium, I think also with some of the older core2duo processors.)

Comment: OK - so now I have downloaded both a 32 bit and a 64 bit ubuntu gnome. The 32 bit works and the 64 bit doesn't. Why?

I am currently using 64 bit - 4GB RAM.

Comment: Maybe it is not really working with a 64-bit operating system. Use what works, 32-bit :-) The new 64-bit versions might need some capability, that is lacking in the computer.

Comment: I didn't vote for the duplicate, but for a different reason - that the problem was already solved. I'll vote to reopen because it's not a duplicate, but you should clarify exactly what you are asking for help with now

Comment: 1. Currently PC is running Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit.

2. I create a USB stick with Ubuntu 17.04 64bit. Does not boot.

3. I create a USB stick with Ubuntu 17.04 32bit. Boots fine.

4. Why? Is it a UEFI or something issue?


This happens on a second PC too.